# Weblogic 10_2 throwing weblogic.application.ModuleException while deplyoing EJB,Struts app?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, weblogic-10.x

Does any one encountered following exception in your experience

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException:
        at weblogic.jdbc.module.JDBCModule.prepare(JDBCModule.java:289)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:93)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:387)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:37)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:58)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
weblogic.common.ResourceException: weblogic.common.ResourceException: DataSource(upanDataSource) can't be created with non-existent Pool (connection or multi) (upanPool)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceManager.checkDataSource(DataSourceManager.java:236)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceManager.checkDataSource(DataSourceManager.java:204)
        at weblogic.jdbc.module.JDBCModule.prepare(JDBCModule.java:277)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:93)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:387)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Please dont mind i am new to weblogic

Comment: Hey friends,i upgraded to 11 and it is resolved